# Error when filtering DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I am reading a `DataFrame` from a CSV file like this:

```
val rawData = sqlContext.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "false")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load(url)
```

Then, I am attempting to filter it by the following criterion:
The first element of each row should be a string containing either `AAA` or `BBB`.
For this, I have the code:

```
val filteredData = rawData.filter(me => (me(0).toString.contains("AAA") || me(0).toString.contains("BBB")))
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
Error:(104, 41) missing parameter type
    val filteredData = rawData.filter(me => (me(0).toString.contains("AAA") || me(0).toString.contains("BBB")))
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use filter in a different way. Try something like this:

```
val dataArray = Array(("AAA", 1), ("ABC", 2), ("ABCBBB", 3))
val rawData: DataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(dataArray)

rawData.filter(rawData("_1").contains("AAA") || rawData("_1").contains("BBB")).show()
```

The result will be:

```
+------+---+
|    _1| _2|
+------+---+
|   AAA|  1|
|ABCBBB|  3|
+------+---+
```

Comment: I don't understand how this filter works. Shouldn't it take `rawData` element by element?

Comment: As you are working with `DataFrame`s you need to define what we need to do with the `Column`s (like in SQL). Your approach would work if you were using `RDD`s.